# Store on USB at system boot

Tags: boot, usb, backup

I am interested in storing data on a USB drive every time my system boots. I have placed a script in the init.d directory but I am not able to copy my data in the USB stick. Is it possible that the USB drive is not available at booting? I know the path for the usb drives is

```
/media/myUSB
```

From the init.d script, I tried

```
ls /media/ > output.txt
```

and I had an output in the txt file of myUSB. However, when I did

```
ls /media/myUSB > output.txt
```

I had no output.

Can anyone please help me.

Edit:

If I do

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

I get this output:

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1              44    15679439     7839698    b  W95 FAT32
```

Is the proposed line (see answer below) going to change? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In order to mount a device during boot, it has to be mapped in /etc/fstab, otherwise it will only be mounted when the user logs in because gnome or unity would detect external devices.

First, you need to know the path to the usb device, which is not the same as /media/myUSB (that's where the device is mounted). To do so, execute:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

You should see diferent devices, typically /dev/sda1 /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb1... The letter identify physical discs, while the numbers identify partitions so presumably an external usb should be at least "b". In my system I have this:

```
/dev/sda1             2048   97656344  97654297  46,6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2         97656832 1074219007 976562176 465,7G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       1074219008 1082032127   7813120   3,7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda4  *    1082032128 1953521663 871489536 415,6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *    16128 7831551 7815424  3,7G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

As you can see, I have a main drive with four partitions, and an external usb with only one. Once you know which partition is your usb, add it to fstab with your favourite editor (you'll need administrator privileges). The new line should look something like this:

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/myUSB/ ntfs-3g defaults,auto,umask=000,users,rw 0 0
```

Note that this is an example, your device may have a different number or filesystem (NTFS in my case). If you add more information to your question perhaps somebody can point you to the exact syntax.

Comment: I placed my output as an answer you that you can see it clearly.